# What do chairs do?

Tags: this-war-of-mine

I haven't quite grasped the purpose of chairs. Your survivors will sit on them from time to time when idling, but what is the benefit?

- Do they reduce stress? Is there any point in actively sending your crew to sit on them?
- Is there any point in building multiple chairs? The "our stuff" dialog suggests this.
- How do more expensive chairs like the arm chair differ from normal chairs?

Answer (score 7):

if a survivor goes and sits in a chair without you making him do it, don't bother him, he'll be reading a book (the more you have, the better) and it will help reduce sadness. an armchair would obviously be more comfortable, therefore helping more. unfortunately, there isn't any "guide" that tells us exactly what to do and how things will work out according to different actions, you just have to try things and see it for yourself. nonetheless, I hope I was of any help! :)